# How Do I Use Constructor Injection In Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using the MVVM pattern with Xamarin Forms.
I have my MainPage & MainPageViewModel.
My MainPageViewModel has a constructor that takes a IMyClass parameter.

```
public AboutViewModel(IMyClass mClass)
{
   .....
```

If I use the code behind  MainPage.xaml.cs and do something like this

```
  IMyClass myclass = new MyClass();
  BindingContext = new AboutViewModel(myClass);
```

Is this the correct way? How should I register IMyClass so that I have the app create an instance when required?

Comment: Sounds like you need a "ConfigureServices" method in [DI in ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0), or you can try NuGet packages like DryIoc

Comment: @PaulStanley About Dependency Injection, please take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, you can use the TinyIoC.
Option 2, you can try the DependencyService integrated in Xamarin.

Here is a sample code you can try:
App.xaml.cs

```
...
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DependencyService.Register<MyClass>();
   ...
}
...
```

your Page.xaml.cs

```
 BindingContext = new ViewModel();
```

Your ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   ...

   IMyClass _myClass;
...
   public ViewModel()
   {
      _myClass = DependencyService.Get<IMyClass>();
      ...
   } 
...
```